# User agent style sheet forced

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am working on a site developed in ASP.net already.

I was changing the .master file for the website and decided that an upgrade to HTML 5 was required.

So I removed the default `xmls` tag from the HTML tag in the .master file and this had no visible effect on the site. But as soon as I change the `DOCTYPE` to the format for HTML 5 all the tables in my site default to the user agent style sheet font size.

So in my .css file I added the following codes:

```
table > tr{
    font-size:8px;
}

table > tr > td, table > tr > th{
    font-size:8px;
}

body{
    font-size:8px;
}
```

As far as my knowledge goes this will overwrite ALL default style sheet values and replace them with the css values.

But instead (When using Google Chrome developer tools) I can see that the default agent style sheet value is preferred to the actual value.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this or how this problem occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the DOM. The start and end tags for the `tbody` element are optional, but the element is mandatory. `table > tr` won't match anything because a table row can't be the child of a table, only a grandchild.

[image: DOM]